# Why animate not working when scroll to top?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-animate

I have problem whith progress bar. When page is load, horizontal progress bar in header animate to specified width. When we start scroll page, this bar should animate from 100% width to 0% width and it works. But when we scroll to top, this progress bar not working.

```
var loader = $('#dottedProgressBar');
var loader2 = $('#dottedProgressBar2');
var loader3 = $('#dottedProgressBar3');
var time = 1300; 
var max_width = loader.width();
var max_width2 = loader2.width();
var max_width3 = loader3.width();

loader.width(0);
loader2.width(0);
loader3.width(0);


    loader.animate({
        width: max_width
    }, time);

    loader2.animate({
        width: max_width2
    }, time);

    loader3.animate({
        width: max_width3
    }, time);       

 $(document).scroll(function(){

    if ($(document).scrollTop() > 0) {

            loader.animate({
                width: '0px',
                opacity: '0'
             }, 1300);

            loader2.animate({
                width: '0px',
                opacity: '0'
             }, 1300);

            loader3.animate({
                width: '0px',
                opacity: '0'
             }, 1300);              
        }

        if ($(document).scrollTop() == 0){

            loader.animate({
                width: '550px',
                opacity: '1'
            }, 300);

            loader2.animate({
                width: '550px',
                opacity: '1'
            }, 300);

            loader3.animate({
                width: '500px',
                opacity: '1'
            }, 300);    
        }
```

Comment: can you provide html so i can look at it in jsfiddle?

Comment: here is code in jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/d43pgthL/3/